# Upper bound of the number of near-square primes

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers

Wikipedia page on [Landau problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_problems#Near-square_primes) states, without any reference:

> The Brun sieve establishes an upper bound on the density of primes having the form ${p=n^{2}+1}$: there are $O(\sqrt x/\log x)$ such primes up to $x$.

Can someone please post a reference, or prove it, if trivial?

Answer (score 2):

It's not trivial; it follows from standard but technically difficult general theorems of sieve theory. The upper bound on the number of such primes follows from an upper bound for the number of integers of the form $n^2+1$ up to $x$ that have no prime factors less than $x^{1/5}$ or something like that. Possible reading: [Terry Tao's notes](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/01/21/254a-notes-4-some-sieve-theory/), in particular Exercise 27.